# Billing API v3 IabHelper NullPointerException

Tags: android, in-app-billing

**edit 4/15:** Catching nullpointer in IabHelper appears to have stopped this problem.  I am no longer seeing the exceptions being thrown, I'm going to accept this as an answer.

---

**edit 4/04:** A little bit of a deeper dive.  There are try catch blocks that handle RemoteExceptions and JSONExceptions for the queryPurchases method, but no NullPointerException handling.  What I am going to try is include NullPointer Exception handling so IabHelper looks like this when trying to querySkuDetails:

```
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new IabException(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "NullPointer while refreshing inventory.", e);
    }
```

I just filed a bug on this:

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=114

---

**edit 3/25:**  well, still receiving this crash... now it happens while trying to get a context at line 3 of the following excerpt from IabHelper:

```
int queryPurchases(Inventory inv, String itemType) throws JSONException, RemoteException {
    logDebug("Querying owned items, item type: " + itemType);
    logDebug("Package name: " + mContext.getPackageName());
```

This is frustrating because in my manifest I always use the full path name of my app for "name".

Example "com.myappname.blah.ClassName"

I've also tried passing this, MyClass.this, getApplicationContext() to mHelper.  However they all produce the same NullPointer results randomly from devices in the wild.  I also tried name=".MyClass" in the manifest.  This is what it looks like currently:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(MyClass.this, myKey);
```

---

**edit** 3/18/13: I am still receiving exceptions, even with the new IabHelper version deployed on 3/17.

I am starting to see a pattern here, that the crashes are all when trying to get a context when executing mContext.getPackageName().  I'm curious why this works on all of my test devices, and I can't reproduce this crash, and only seems to be on a small number of devices.

Here is the new crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(SourceFile:836)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(SourceFile:558)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(SourceFile:522)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper$2.run(SourceFile:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Caused by IabHelper...

```
line 836: logDebug("Package name: " + mContext.getPackageName());
```

---

**edit** 3/17/13: I see that there have been many bug fixes published over the past several months, I will try the latest code available here and see if this resolves the problem:

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util

---

In one of my apps, I am using the billing API and the boilerplate code included with it.

I am using the latest version of billing API available via the SDK manager as of 3/16/2013.

In my activity, I query the inventory using the following:

```
final List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
skuList.add("sku1");
skuList.add("sku2");
skuList.add("sku3");
if (skuList != null) {
    if (skuList.size() > 0) {
        try {
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mGotInventoryListener);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving multiple NullPointerException reports in the wild from the IabHelper class for the following devices.  I can't reproduce the issue and can't find any information regarding these crashes, and is the reason why I am posting this question.

I have countless other checks for nulls and try/catch blocks in the "developer facing" part of the billing API, including within onQueryInventoryFinished, so I know this exception is not being thrown from "my code" (because I'm not capturing crashes from any of my app's classes), but instead is being thrown from within the IabHelper itself.  I have not modified the IabHelper other than this recommended fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737699

**Crash #1 Galaxy Nexus**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.querySkuDetails(SourceFile:802)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(SourceFile:471)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper$2.run(SourceFile:521)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Caused by IabHelper...

```
line 802: Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, mContext.getPackageName(), ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, querySkus);
```

**Crash #2 Samsung GT-S5570L**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(SourceFile:735)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(SourceFile:465)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper$2.run(SourceFile:521)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Caused by IabHelper...

```
line 735: Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, continueToken);
```

Comment: I am getting the following crash log. `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(SourceFile:735)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(SourceFile:465)
    at com.myapp.util.IabHelper$2.run(SourceFile:521)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)` Has anyone figured oout what might be causing this. I am checking if connection is established before querying purchases.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing still, even with the latest code from a couple weeks ago.  It is very frustrating, but it does appear to be related to contexts.  I've tried different ways of passing context to IabHelper, but they all seem to crash.  In my latest release I commented out the log line that was throwing the exception, but now it is just crashing in a different place.

Comment: @glo I just filed a bug on this: https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=114

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**edit 4/15:** Catching nullpointer in IabHelper appears to have stopped this problem.  I am no longer seeing the exceptions being thrown, I'm going to accept this as an answer.

---

**edit 4/04:** A little bit of a deeper dive.  There are try catch blocks that handle RemoteExceptions and JSONExceptions for the queryPurchases method, but no NullPointerException handling.  What I am going to try is include NullPointer Exception handling so IabHelper looks like this when trying to querySkuDetails:

```
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new IabException(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "NullPointer while refreshing inventory.", e);
    }
```

I just filed a bug on this:

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=114

---

Change

```
        if (querySkuDetails) {
            r = querySkuDetails(ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, inv, moreItemSkus);
            if (r != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                throw new IabException(r, "Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of items).");
            }
        }
```

to

```
        if (querySkuDetails) {
            try {
                r = querySkuDetails(ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, inv, moreItemSkus);
                if (r != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                    throw new IabException(r, "Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of items).");
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw new IabException(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "NPE while refreshing inventory.", e);
            }
        }
```

Change

```
            if (querySkuDetails) {
                r = querySkuDetails(ITEM_TYPE_SUBS, inv, moreSubsSkus);
                if (r != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                    throw new IabException(r, "Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of subscriptions).");
                }
            }
```

to

```
            if (querySkuDetails) {
                try {
                    r = querySkuDetails(ITEM_TYPE_SUBS, inv, moreSubsSkus);
                    if (r != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                        throw new IabException(r, "Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of subscriptions).");
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    throw new IabException(IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR, "NPE while refreshing inventory.", e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Filing a bug may not be helpful, since the repo is deprecated.

Comment: where should i put this catch?

Comment: Based on my read of the code, catching the error should just remove the crash, rather than fix the source issue where purchases won't work in this scenario; is that correct? If so, how would one go about fixing the source issue (ensuring the necessary objects are in memory)?

Answer (score 20):

You are probably using async operations. The current IabHelper is not safe in case you use the ...async methods. The problem is that in any moment an async operation is running dispose can be called on the main thread. In this case you will get NullPointerExceptions and IllegalStateExceptions.

Here is the patch fixing it:

```
Index: src/com/evotegra/aCoDriver/iabUtil/IabHelper.java
===================================================================
--- src/com/evotegra/aCoDriver/iabUtil/IabHelper.java   (revision 1162)
+++ src/com/evotegra/aCoDriver/iabUtil/IabHelper.java   (working copy)
@@ -86,7 +86,10 @@

     // Is an asynchronous operation in progress?
     // (only one at a time can be in progress)
-    boolean mAsyncInProgress = false;
+    volatile boolean mAsyncInProgress = false;
+    
+    // is set to true if dispose is called while a thread is running. Allows graceful shutdown
+    volatile boolean mDisposeRequested = false;

     // (for logging/debugging)
     // if mAsyncInProgress == true, what asynchronous operation is in progress?
@@ -285,6 +288,12 @@
      * disposed of, it can't be used again.
      */
     public void dispose() {
+       // do not dispose while an async Thread is running. Will cause all kinds of exceptions.
+       // In this case dispose must be called from thread after setting mAsyncInProgress to true
+       if (mAsyncInProgress) {
+           mDisposeRequested = true;
+           return;
+       }
         logDebug("Disposing.");
         mSetupDone = false;
         if (mServiceConn != null) {
@@ -827,6 +836,7 @@
         logDebug("Ending async operation: " + mAsyncOperation);
         mAsyncOperation = "";
         mAsyncInProgress = false;
+        if (mDisposeRequested) IabHelper.this.dispose();
     }
```

Or download the patch here.
http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=139&thanks=139&ts=1375614409

Comment: I use a single thread executor to schedule all async operations subsequently. Also the dispose method. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222015/in-app-billing-v3-illegalargumentexception-using-iabhelper.

Comment: Unfortunately the IabHelper has several other flaws. In general it is not production ready and imo should **not** be used in any public app. I informed the owner of the code at Google trevorjohns@google.com I got even an reply saying "Developer told me it is fixed in current version" but in fact it is not. Maybe you write him an email to kindly ask them to fix it.

Comment: Does this patch fix *this* bug or not?

Comment: It fixes a source of NullPointerException in IabHelper. But there are many bugs in this code.

Comment: How do you use this patch in an Android project ? Thanks.

Comment: I think this patch has flaws as well. If there is a purchase flow in progress, and the device is rotated, the existing iabHelper instance will never receive a flagEndAsync because onActivityResult will be received by the new activity and thus the new iabHelper instance instead (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20531117/2669960). Try to remove (or catch and return) the illegal state exceptions thrown within iabHelper (as far as I can tell, they are there to make sure devs are using the library 'correctly', but the exceptions can arise from a legitimate concurrency issue!). Catching NPE is good.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modify the beginning of the `queryPurchases` method to look like this:

```
int queryPurchases(Inventory inv, String itemType) throws JSONException, RemoteException {
        // Query purchases
        //logDebug("Querying owned items, item type: " + itemType);
       //logDebug("Package name: " + mContext.getPackageName());
       boolean verificationFailed = false;
       String continueToken = null;

        do {
//            logDebug("Calling getPurchases with continuation token: " + continueToken);
            if(mDisposed || mService==null) return IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
            Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                    itemType, continueToken);
```

Thanks to  [sebastie](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=114#c1) for pointing out the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

[tmanthey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837119) [patch](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=139&thanks=139&ts=1375614409) also requires

```
mDisposeRequested = false;
```

after the disposing takes place

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting this error on the emulator, it may be a very simple thing which happens in more than a half cases.

Check that you're using Google API SDK and not regular SDK!!!

Answer (score -1):

The IabHelper is obsolete and has been replaced by the BillingClient.
See https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html

Comment: It is not obsolete, but rather an alternative. As stated "To simplify development with the In-app Billing API, you can use the Play Billing Library. This library is an in-app billing client developed as a wrapper on top of the Android Interface Definition Language file that interacts with the In-app Billing API. "

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted IabHelper is obsolete "We have no more plans to update the Trivial Drive v1, that uses the IABHelper." https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/45#issuecomment-364187315

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted "But, it won't be updated" https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/89#issuecomment-339506733