# In App Billing v3 IllegalArgumentException using IabHelper

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've had in app billing v3 implemented in my app for about a week now.  I used a lot of android's sample code to simplify the integration.  I've been logging a crash fairly often that I can't seem to reproduce:

```
Exception Type: java.lang.RuntimeException
Reason: Unable to destroy activity    {[package].billing.BillingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: [package].billing.util.IabHelper$1@40646a70
```

It seems to be breaking on this line:

```
if (mContext != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);
```

I'm binding this service in my onCreate method and disposing it in my onDestroy method (which is where this error is logged).  Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue but on android emulator. Billing v3 requires that Google Play app should be launched at least once and since the emulator lack of Google Play app it cannot set up helper and cannot dispose it in onDestroy().

My personal workaround is just skipping that error in try/catch:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (bHelper != null){
        try {
            bHelper.dispose();
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{}
    }
    bHelper = null;
}
```

Add this in every onDestroy() where you dispose helper. Works fine for me.

Comment: This is an ugly solution and programming style (catching exception and doing nothing about them). You should find the cause of the problem and not hide the effect. The cause is that the service is not connected, so mService = null (as Sam noticed) and mSetupDone = false. You could check either of them to avoid performing unbind for a service that is not bind.

Comment: Even if this may looks ugly, it works nice. My crash was given by the activity being restarted - a.finish(); startActivity(a); - In fact, the amount of time the service normally took to close itself was the main problem. I think this could be easily handled by delaying this call:
bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); by a couple of seconds. That was my case.

Answer (score 34):

You could replace the line you mentioned:

```
if (mContext != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);
```

by this line

```
if (mContext != null && mService != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 16):

I checked out the latest version of the [sample project](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java?r=5f6b7abfd0534acd5bfc7c14436f4500c99e0358) and up to today my recommendation is to currently to **NOT** use `IabHelper`. It is massively flawed.

To give you an idea:

1.) the async methods of `IabHelper` start a new thread. If `IabHelper.dispose()` is called while a thread is running you will always get various exceptions you cannot even handle.

2.) If the connection to the billing service goes down, they set it to `null`. But apart from that they **never** check if `mService` is `null` before accessing the methods. So it will always crash with `NullPointerException` in this case.

```
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                logDebug("Billing service disconnected.");
                mService = null;
```

and this is just the tip of the ice berg. Seriously I do not understand how somebody can publish this as reference code.

Comment: I agree. IabHelper has lots of errors related to dealing with concurrent async calls. For example, it uses unsynchronized flags to indicate already running operations. I modfified IabHelper to use a single thread executor and execute the async operations one at a time. This counts also for the dispose-method. Still not perfect but thread safe.

Comment: @Joerg Could you publish the diff so we can see your changes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `IabHelper` class is working in a normal way.

What you need to do is:
when you call `startSetup` for the helper, you need to pass a callback `IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener` which will tell you the result of starting setup. If you get failure in the callback, the service connection with the google play services was not established. 
You should handle future calls to `IabHelper` depending upon the result received in `IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener`. You can surely keep a `boolean` field to know what was the status.

The answer [sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327172/sam) provided is actually a trick (in his own words). The helper classes aren't supposed to throw exceptions so that the user of those classes can implement some task in such scenarios.

And of-course, `try/catch` is best way if you don't want to go in details (whenever anything breaks due to exception, surely first thing which comes in mind is to put that in a `try/catch` block).