# Unfortunately, appname is stopped

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android Game and when the code is executed in my Android device, it shows "Unfortunately, appname has stop working"

Here is the logcat
    06-27 17:29:08.254: D/AndroidRuntime(704): Shutting down VM
    06-27 17:29:08.254: W/dalvikvm(704): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2ba041f8)
    06-27 17:29:08.264: W/System.err(704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy   activity {com.rookiegames.sher/com.rookiegames.sher.PlayActivity}:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:  com.rookiegames.sher.inappbilling.util.IabHelper$1@2c0c5198
    06-27 17:29:08.264: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3112)
    06-27 17:29:08.274: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
    06-27 17:29:08.274: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    06-27 17:29:08.274: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1180)
    06-27 17:29:08.274: W/System.err(704):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-27 17:29:08.274: W/System.err(704):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-27 17:29:08.274: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    06-27 17:29:08.284: W/System.err(704):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-27 17:29:08.284: W/System.err(704):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-27 17:29:08.294: W/System.err(704):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-27 17:29:08.294: W/System.err(704):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-27 17:29:08.294: W/System.err(704):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-27 17:29:08.294: W/System.err(704): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.rookiegames.sher.inappbilling.util.IabHelper$1@2c0c5198
    06-27 17:29:08.304: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:888)
    06-27 17:29:08.304: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1147)
    06-27 17:29:08.304: W/System.err(704):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:375)
    06-27 17:29:08.314: W/System.err(704):  at com.rookiegames.sher.inappbilling.util.IabHelper.dispose(IabHelper.java:294)
    06-27 17:29:08.314: W/System.err(704):  at com.rookiegames.sher.PlayActivity.onDestroy(PlayActivity.java:243)
    06-27 17:29:08.314: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:4629)
    06-27 17:29:08.314: W/System.err(704):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1079)

Manifest

```
package="com.rookiegames.sher"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="6"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<!-- Store the DB on SD CARD -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- Use GP Billing -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.rookiegames.sher.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"   ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.rookiegames.sher.CategoriesActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoTitle" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.rookiegames.sher.LevelsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoTitle" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.rookiegames.sher.WordsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoTitle" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.rookiegames.sher.PlayActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme.NoTitle" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tapjoy.TJCOffersWebView"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyFullScreenAdWebView"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyDailyRewardAdWebView"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyVideoView"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />

    <activity
  android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode">
```

Comment: [tag:stop] was the only tag you could think to put on this question? It didn't occur to you that maybe [tag:android] and/or [tag:java] might have *some* relevance here? Also, some attempt to explain your current situation, the current problem and what attempts you've made to solve it would be nice before you throw hundreds of lines of what looks like log output at us.

Comment: Huge log, no tags and no code.

Answer (score 0):

No question, No Code? So please ask what exactly is Your problem and please post some relevant Code. But so far I can see, It seems to be an issue on the IabHelper class:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.rookiegames.sher.inappbilling.util.IabHelper$1@2c0c5198
```

Here is another post about this.

[In App Billing v3 IllegalArgumentException using IabHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222015/in-app-billing-v3-illegalargumentexception-using-iabhelper)