# Android 5 Lollipop InAppBilling doesn't work

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm experiencing issues with InApp Billing on Android 5.

I'm always getting following error:

```
11-06 13:09:17.533: D/Finsky(2105): [1] PurchaseFragment.handleError: Error: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=12}
11-06 13:09:17.533: D/Finsky(2105): [1] PurchaseFragment.fail: Purchase failed: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=12}
```

The app correctly gets all packages from the play store billing service but the payment produces the error: "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information."

On device Using Android 4.4 (Nexus 5) this error doesn't appear and I'm taken straight to the payment.

This error appears also when I use the application from here: [Current Android IAB reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185808/current-android-iab-reference/26297205#26297205) (Also including creation of explicit intent from different answer)

I went through the checklist here: [This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla/22469253#22469253)

Tested on devices: Nexus 5, Nexus 7 and Nexus 9 running all slightly different versions of developer preview and (in case of Nexus 9) stock Android 5 so it's not device depending. Test accounts are different on each device.

Also this problem occurs when both using native java code and adobe air application with native extension.

Comment: Consider filing this issue @ https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/wiki/FilingIssues

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you are experiencing trouble with?

Comment: The code is in the linked answer. I don't want to put here the dropbox link for something I didn't create. I't the last link there. The sample is so good so I didn't modify it almost at all (modifications are only in matter of package name, item name etc.) but my problem is not relevant to the question there because the app is not crashing nor throwing exception. All I get is this debug message into the logcat and error screen described above. The strangest thing is that it work perfectly on android 4.4 so there is no logical mistake in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it may be an issue with a change in the SHA1 algo in Lollipop.
See the link below:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1942&q=Type%3DDefect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&start=400

Comment: Yeah... looks like signing with different certificate works but unfortunately that is not a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, however on Android 4.4.4.

The reason was (I believe) that I tried to do a test purchase with the Google Id that is linked with my Google Play Console Account.

I went to Google Play on my phone, chose a different Google Id Account, and added the different account to Google Play Console --> Settings --> Acount Details --> License Testing.

Then I still received the error when I tried to do the test purchase ...

Then I rebooted the phone and then in worked. I guess you have to reboot the phone to make sure it uses the right account to do the purchase.

Comment: Update: I received this error again - had to reboot the phone - error again, next try it worked... I think it is related to testing with the test accounts.

Comment: Update: I received the error again, and this time I believe I found the real reason: When you are implementing in-app billing, you need to upload an apk according to the documentation.

Comment: Update2: I received the error again, and this time I believe I found the real reason: When you are implementing in-app billing, you need to upload an apk according to the documentation. Then when you're testing, you can simply install your latest version on your mobile, however, the versonCode has to be the same as the versionCode of your uploaded apk. After I received this error the last time, I downgraded the versionCode to the one currently uploaded to the Google Play Console, and then in worked. Heureka!

Comment: For your case there is really nice checklist in the link I postet in the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla/22469253#22469253 ... Going through that would solve your problem immediately. Issue I was addressing (and solved) is related to wrong certificates generated by Air SDK.